# I need to schedule a job in jenkins that runs every 15th working day. Is it possible to do so?

Tags: jenkins

00 15 * * 1-5 will run the job for every day. But I need to run it only on 15th working day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you had `0 0 15 * *`, should have worked (missed a space).

Answer (score 0):

CRON expression fields are

- minutes,
- hours,
- day of month,
- month,
- day of week, and
- year (optional)

If you wanted to run a job on the 15th day of the month, you would do `* * 15 * *`

In your example, you already pass in minutes, hours and day of week. You just need to change it to `00 15 15 * 1-5` where the 3rd element is the day of the month. If the 15th isn't a working week day (Saturday or Sunday), it will be skipped.